# Obtaining the start and end dates from a single column of data

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the Start and End date of a product's sales period from a column of data that is a dummy variable for sale. Here is a proxy of the type of data that I am working with:
[image]

The result I am looking for is:

[image]

The actual data set I am working on is much larger than this and does not necessarily look at just 2010-01 to 2011-12.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like get min and max with categories of a variable would have been asked many time before. Have you been unable to find prior questions like this? At any rate you DO need to post an example in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes only one sale per product

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(product = 'Product A', 
                 month = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),
                             as.Date('2010-10-01'),
                             by = 'month'
                             ),
                 onSale = c(rep(0,3), rep(1,4),rep(0,3))
                 )


df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  summarise(saleStart = month[which.min(month[onSale == 1])],
            salend    = month[which.max(month[onSale == 1])]
            )
```

Edit:

```
df <- data.frame(product = 'Product A', 
                 month = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),
                             as.Date('2011-09-01'),
                             by = 'month'
                             ),
                 onSale = c(rep(0,3), rep(1,4),rep(0,3), rep(1,4),rep(0,3), rep(1,4))
                 )


df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  mutate(diff = c(0,diff(onSale))) %>% 
  group_by(product, diff) %>% 
  filter(diff == 1) %>% 
  mutate(monthStart = month, monthEnd = month  %m+% months(1)) %>% 
  select(-month,-diff)
```

Comment: Thank you mr.joshuagordon, what if there were multiple sales per product?