# Create a startime and endtime column from one timestamp column in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, timestamp

I'm trying to identify when an event (cluster, 1 or 2) starts and stops, so I can use timeDiff and relate latlon data to weather data on these stop/start dates. Excluding location data for now, my data look like this (8000+ rows, timestamps are 15 mins apart, 27 unique ids, clusters change within ids 50+ times):

```
dput(head(mydata,80))structure(list(id = c(43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 43486L, 
43486L, 43486L, 43486L), cluster = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), idswitch = c("43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", 
"43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 2 0", "43486 1 1", 
"43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", 
"43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", 
"43486 2 2", "43486 2 2", "43486 2 2"), t_ = structure(c(1661663122, 
1661664035, 1661664948, 1661665900, 1661666812, 1661667724, 1661668637, 
1661669550, 1661670463, 1661671376, 1661672289, 1661673202, 1661674114, 
1661675026, 1661675939, 1661676852, 1661677764, 1661678676, 1661679588, 
1661680501, 1661681414, 1661682326, 1661683239, 1661684151, 1661685063, 
1661685975, 1661686888, 1661687800, 1661688712, 1661689624, 1661690536, 
1661691449, 1661692362, 1661693275, 1661694187, 1661695099, 1661696011, 
1661696923, 1661697835, 1661698747, 1661699659, 1661700571, 1661701483, 
1661702976, 1661703888, 1661704800, 1661705714, 1661706626, 1661707541, 
1661708454, 1661709366, 1661710279, 1661711191, 1661712104, 1661713017, 
1661713930, 1661714842, 1661715755, 1661716669, 1661717583, 1661718496, 
1661719410, 1661720324, 1661721236, 1661722149, 1661723061, 1661723973, 
1661724885, 1661725798, 1661726713, 1661727629, 1661728542, 1661729454, 
1661730370, 1661731283, 1661732196, 1661733109, 1661734022, 1661734934, 
1661735848), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), mode.switches = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is a (slightly modified) chunk to illustrate my problem:

```
id cluster idswitch  t_                  mode.switches
   <int> <fct>   <chr>     <dttm>                      <dbl>
 1 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 00:05:22             0
 2 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 00:20:35             0
 3 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 00:35:48             0
 4 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 00:51:40             0
 5 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 01:06:52             0
 6 43486 1       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 01:22:04             0
```

**I would like an output that looks like this:**

```
idcluster   StartTime           EndTime  
\<chr\>      \<dttm\>              \<dttm\>  
1 43486 2 2022-08-28 00:05:22 2022-08-28 01:22:04  
2 43486 1 2022-08-28 01:22:04 2022-08-28 01:37:17
3 43486 2 2022-08-28 01:37:17 2022-08-28 02:07:43
4 43486 1 2022-08-28 02:07:43 2022-08-31 19:29:55
```

Where event 2 ends at the same time as event 1 starts.

I made id and cluster into one column using paste and made a new col, mode.switches, that sums how many times the event changes per id, thinking that might be helpful (spoiler, it wasn't). Some of my attempts below:

```
mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(mode.switches = cumsum(c(0,as.numeric(diff(cluster))!=0))) %>%
  ungroup()

#First try---------
test <- all %>% 
  group_by(idswitch) %>%
  summarise(
    first = min(t_), 
    last = max(t_)
  )

#This is not what I want. An event stops and starts at the same time, and start/end times are wrong. Events  need to start when the event before them stops.
   idswitch   first               last               
   <chr>      <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 43486 1 1  2022-08-28 16:59:33 2022-08-28 16:59:33
 2 43486 1 11 2022-08-30 14:12:25 2022-08-30 20:47:56
 3 43486 1 13 2022-08-30 21:18:20 2022-08-30 23:04:47
 4 43486 1 15 2022-08-31 14:40:47 2022-08-31 19:29:55
 5 43486 1 17 2022-08-31 20:00:22 2022-08-31 21:46:53

#lead/lag - it still respects idcluster so won't use t_ +1 or -1 of another idcluster, but I need the times related to id and cluster....---------
test2 <- mydata %>%
  group_by(idcluster) %>%
  mutate(start=t_, stop=lead(t_, n=1))
sum(is.na(test$stop)) #606 NAs :(

#same problems------------------
test7<- all %>%
  filter(cluster == "1" | lag(cluster) == "1") %>%
  group_by(mode.switches, id, cluster, gr = cumsum(lag(cluster != "1", default = TRUE))) %>%
  summarise(StartTime = first(t_), 
            EndTime = last(t_)) %>%
  mutate(EndTime = replace(EndTime, StartTime == EndTime, NA)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-gr)
sum(is.na(test7$EndTime)) #378 NAs, lame.
```

Lots of similar questions exist, but none seem to solve my problem:
[Identify start and stop sequences and length of run in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385356/identify-start-and-stop-sequences-and-length-of-run-in-r)
[Create start and end time column from a single datetime column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539118/create-start-and-end-time-column-from-a-single-datetime-column-in-r)
[R Start Column & End Column Time Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737653/r-start-column-end-column-time-log)
[Obtaining the start and end dates from a single column of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599795/obtaining-the-start-and-end-dates-from-a-single-column-of-data)
[How to extract start and end dates from single column in large dataset in R using lubridate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400713/how-to-extract-start-and-end-dates-from-single-column-in-large-dataset-in-r-usin)
[R trying to create start and stop times from single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565829/r-trying-to-create-start-and-stop-times-from-single-column)
[Create start and endtime columns based on multiple conditions in R (dplyr, lubridate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068874/create-start-and-endtime-columns-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-r-dplyr-lubri)

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce the result you deem wrong w/o your data. Your comment in the code chunk also suggests that you are looking for something different than your description. E.g.: What is "the event before"? Preceding rows in the df?

Comment: How can I get readers a better piece of my data to work with? The event before may be a 1 or a 2 in col 'cluster,' so that is a little unclear, I agree.

Comment: @Ben, thank you! I've added 80 rows, so there is a change in cluster. I tried your solution, but it seems to skip the first event in for each id? I might be mistaken there. I did: test12 <- all %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cluster != lag(cluster))

test12$End <- lead(test12$t_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding the data.

You can first `group_by` the `id`. Then, `filter` and keep either the first row for a given `id`, or where there is a change in `cluster`.

Then, you can add an `end` column, which is the following row `lead` value of time.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1 | cluster != lag(cluster)) %>%
  mutate(end = lead(t_))
```

**Output**

```
     id cluster idswitch  t_                  mode.switches end                
  <int> <fct>   <chr>     <dttm>                      <dbl> <dttm>             
1 43486 2       43486 2 0 2022-08-28 01:05:22             0 2022-08-28 17:59:33
2 43486 1       43486 1 1 2022-08-28 17:59:33             1 2022-08-28 18:14:45
3 43486 2       43486 2 2 2022-08-28 18:14:45             2 NA
```